# Y axis scaling issue with small numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, autoscaling

I have an issue with y-scaling for numbers smaller than 1e-10 : they all appear on the same horizontal line.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
file <- structure(list(I = c(-7.254574e-11, -5.649333e-11, -5.015416e-11, 
-4.228137e-11, -3.287486e-11, -2.714915e-11, -2.203692e-11, -1.784489e-11, 
-1.150574e-11, -1.058553e-11, -6.189018e-12, -3.735149e-12, -2.303724e-12, 
6.610914e-13, 1.274374e-12, -3.610768e-13, 5.465134e-12, 6.691699e-12, 
8.020478e-12, 1.139353e-11, 1.537988e-11, 1.926399e-11, 2.130825e-11, 
2.45791e-11, 3.204071e-11, 3.582262e-11, 4.287535e-11, 4.624839e-11, 
5.16657e-11, 6.035387e-11), V = c(-2, -1.867, -1.733, -1.6, -1.467, 
-1.333, -1.2, -1.067, -0.933, -0.8, -0.667, -0.533, -0.4, -0.267, 
-0.133, 0, 0.133, 0.267, 0.4, 0.533, 0.667, 0.8, 0.933, 1.067, 
1.2, 1.333, 1.467, 1.6, 1.733, 1.867)), .Names = c("I", "V"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

plot(file$V,file$I)

gg <- ggplot(file,aes(x = V,y=I))
print(gg + geom_point())
```

As you can see, using the base plot function the points are displayed correctly while using ggplot2 they are displayed on a horizontal line.

I saw a similar post on the mailing list in May 2011, to which Hadley answered that it worked with the development version of ggplot2. However, using the R version described below I still get the error.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tikzDevice_0.6.2 filehash_2.2-1   scales_0.2.0     plyr_1.7.1       reshape2_1.2.1  
[6] ggplot2_0.9.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.15.0        MASS_7.3-18       
 [6] memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3        proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 stringr_0.6       
[11] tools_2.15.0
```

Anyone has a clue ?

Thank you in advance !
Thibaud Ruelle

Comment: +1 a quick test confirms this behavior on my system (ggplot2 0.9.1). Maybe there was a reversion, or ?

Comment: @BenBolker I asked Brian about this in chat, given the connection to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10808056/324364) previous question.

Comment: @joran Yes it seems the two posts could be merged. Sorry for not having found it with my research.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have found it if I hadn't specifically remembered seeing and commenting on the previous one.

Comment: However, the manual scaling option can not (or hardly at least) be applied to my case, since I have hundreds of these files to plot and analyze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brian Diggs commented in response to [a related post that @joran pointed to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808056/producing-this-base-plot-with-ggplot2-is-this-ggplot2-bug), the problem's being caused by the function `scales::zero_range()`. It uses `all.equal()` to test whether the smallest and largest y-values are within `tolerance = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5 = 1.490116e-08` of one another; if they are, the data are plotted with the "zero scale" used in your example.

As a temporary fix, you can use `fixInNamespace()` to remove the offending bit of `zero_range()`.

```
library(scales)  ## (The scales package needs to be on your search path)
fixInNamespace("zero_range", pos="package:scales")
```

In the editor launched by `fixInNamespace()`, replace this definition of `zero_range()`:

```
function (x) 
{
    length(x) == 1 || isTRUE(all.equal(x[1] - x[2], 0))
}
```

with this one (making sure to save the edited version):

```
function (x) 
{
    length(x) == 1 
}
```

The code you supplied then runs just fine:

[image]

Comment: You could also adjust the `tolerance` argument in `all.equal`, I suppose.

Comment: @joran -- Any idea what would be a better value? I don't know what pathology Hadley's trying to protect against with this bit of code, so don't know how low it's safe to go... (So of course I went and removed the protection all together ;)

Comment: Well, `zero_range` is generally passed a vector with the min/max, so you want _some_ check there for when they're the same. Maybe just just check if `x[1] == x[2]`? I feel like there are floating point edge cases here I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It makes sense to me, but does not work with the code I use. I cleared my workspace, did the fix after loading scales, then loaded ggplot2, then ran the code I provided. Maybe scales is not in my search path, how can I make sure ?

Comment: @ThibaudRuelle -- Type `search()`, and if you see `package:scales` in the results, it's on your search path. Also, you have to make sure that you **save** the edited version of `zero_range`. (Interestingly, even when you've appropriately edited the code, typing `zero_range` will print the *un*edited version.)

Comment: @joran -- Yeah, it's those edge cases that I don't understand either. Presumably there was a reason not to use `==`, but just as clearly, `all.equal()` with the default tolerance is *too* conservative.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks again. It seems I did not find how to properly save zero_range() : when I make your fix, the function appears the way it should but `zero_range(c(1e-11,2e-11,3e-11))` gives `TRUE` so the changes have not been made. (scales is in my search path).

Comment: @ThibaudRuelle -- Have a look instead at the version (?) that's in the namespace: `scales:::zero_range(range(c(1e-11,2e-11,3e-11)))`. That should return `FALSE` if you've succeeded in saving the edits.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes, this is working. Now I need to make ggplot2 use this version instead of the current one :)

Comment: I've updated a bug report about this: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/550

Comment: I get different results by typing `zero_range` (the original function) and `scales:::zero_range` (the corrected function), but both with `<environment: namespace:scales>` at the end. I guess I will make a new post.   I also think that we will not get anymore resuts on this issue before a clean fix is made, so I will validate your answer, thank you again JoshO'Brien. Edit : After restarting R, I get the right curve, but with no y-ticks, good enough for me.